# Copy command using triggers to children tables is slower than inserting directly

Tags: postgresql

I see that the performance for "copy from" statement (postgresql) degrading when I insert through a parent table rather than inserting directly into children. Let me explain this.

I have a table structure like this:
A
|-> A1
|-> A2
|-> A3
.
.
|-> An

where A1...An inherits from A.

There is a trigger before_insert_into_A which inserts into one of the tables A1...An before inserting into A.

Case 1: So I do a 'copy from' command where I copy from a file into the table A. Each row is redirected using the trigger to one of the children table. I do this for a large number of tuples (few millions).

Case 2: Now, in another attempt, I do a 'copy from' and insert directly into one of the children, instead of copying into parent and going through the triggers.

In both the cases, I insert a few million rows record the insert throughput (number of rows inserted per second). I find that in case 2, the throughput is almost twice or thrice the throughput in case 1.

So here's my question finally. Is the difference in throughput expected? Will using triggers slow down the insert this much? If it is not expected, is there a problem with how the trigger function is? Is there any way to increase the throughput in case 1?

PS: I use postgres 8.3 for now. So maybe this isn't the case in postgresql 9.x? Haven't tested this in postgres 9.x.

Comment: Yes, triggers have high overhead. Your benchmarks are accurate and expected. Triggers have high overhead even in Postgresql 9.3.

Comment: _inserts into one of the tables A1...An before inserting into A_: did you mean **instead** of inserting into A? Otherwise, it's inserting twice each row.

Comment: It's inserting only once. It's not inserting into A. It's inserting into one of A1...An